# to print the sum of 5 elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

well when i am trying to run this code below in java it is telling out of bounds but the program is logically correct:

```
import java.io.*;
class array2
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a[]=new int[5];
        int i,sum=0;

        for(i=1;i<=5;i++) { 
            System.out.println("enter the numbers");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            sum=sum+a[i];
        }

        System.out.println(+sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should formate your code, it's hard to read now

Comment: Man you should read about Java before coding. Arrays are zero-indexed in 90% of programming languages, as the answers tell you.

Comment: Arrays start at 0 so the last index is `array.length - 1`

Comment: Are you sure you need an array?

Comment: but the logic is correct if i put 0 then it should be for(i=0;i<5;i++) and if i put 1 it should be for(i=1;i<=5;i++)

Comment: there is no a[5], just a[0],a[1]...a[4] so no the logic is not correct

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
...
System.out.println(+sum);
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
...
System.out.println(sum);
```

So as to start from the first element, 0 indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Your creating an array, this means its position starts at `0` you are starting at `1` and trying to run for 5 times.  try starting at 0:

```
import java.io.*;
    class array2
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a[]=new int[5];
    int i,sum=0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    { 
    System.out.println("enter the numbers");
    a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    sum=sum+a[i];
    }
    System.out.println(+sum);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays start at 0 and end at `length - 1` but you don't need any array here.  You can do

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
long sum = IntStream.range(0, 5)
                    .map(i -> {
                         System.out.println("enter the numbers");
                         return sc.nextInt();
                     })
                    .sum();
System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
```